# REST API best practise

Tags: rest, database-design

I wonder what best practise for a case like this in terms of the REST API and the database design.

The scenario is that we have books that have pages that have words.

- Books has an external id (`my_external_id` as example) that I want to use to reference it.

  `GET /books/my_external_id/`
- I want to reference pages by page number (1,2,3 etc) or an external page id (`my_external_page_id` which will be unique). Do I need to define how which type of page id I am referencing somehow?

  `GET /books/my_external_id/pages/1`

  `PUT /books/my_external_id/pages/1`

  `GET /pages/my_external_page_id`

  `PUT /pages/my_external_page_id`
- I want to get and add words based on page number for book.

  `GET /books/my_external_id/pages/1/words`

  `PUT /books/my_external_id/pages/1/words`

  `GET /pages/my_external_page_id/words`

  `PUT /pages/my_external_page_id/words`

What would the complete solution be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to define how which type of page id I am referencing
>   somehow?
>   I would say that depends on what you're querying

If you're `GET`ting a book, books have pages numbered sequentially from 1.

```
GET /books/my_external_id/pages/1
```

the above makes sense to me as you're asking for `Page` 1 of the `Book` identified by `my_external_id`. That `Page` will have `Word`s associated with it. So your data model is made of up these objects:

`Book` has 1 or more `Page` has 1 or more `Word`

The above can be used to model your world of books, pages and words. `my_external_id` is just used to enter that world of books. i.e. it's the only way you have of getting access to a book. If you go into a physical library, you need a library membership card to get a book out but you don't need that card to read the book as the book has intrinsic attributes such as pages and words. So once you have used `my_external_id` (in effect, your library card) to get your book, you should be able to use the data model from then on:

```
GET /books/my_external_id/pages/1
GET /books/my_external_id/pages/1/words/
GET /books/my_external_id/pages/1/words/23
```

Your other entry points (mini library cards?) can be used to enter your data model at different points, assuming `my_external_page_id` and `my_external_word_id` are unique across all books:

```
GET /pages/my_external_page_id
GET /words/my_external_word_id
```

but after that you'd be in 'data model' mode, i.e. GET the 50th word on the page:

```
GET /pages/my_external_page_id/50
```

using `50`th word instead of `my_external_word_id`, which is an entry point and not the data model (`50`).

Updating works the same. Just choose which model object to work on:

get the 10th page of a book:

```
GET /pages/my_external_page_id
```

get all the words for that page:

```
GET /pages/my_external_page_id/words
```

update the 20th word on the 10th page:

```
PUT /pages/my_external_page_id/words/20
```

The above uses the data model approach. `my_external_page_id` gets you a `Page` which has `Word` instances and you want to update the 20th `Word` instance, rather than using `my_external_word_id` which would return a single `Word` instance.

Ultimately, your model could be:

`Book` has `id`, `title`, `author`, `isbn`, `numberOfPages` and `listOfPages` a list of `Page` instances.

`Page` has `id`, and a list of `Word` instances. It could also have `number` but that would only be relevant to the `Book` that owned it. To get the 10th `Page` of the `Book` you could either do it via the `listOfPages` in `Book` or iterate `listOfPages` until you find a `Page` with `number = 10`.

Word has `id` and `text`.

That should be enough unless you want to access `Page` and `Word` instances independently of `Book` instances but you'd ultimately need a `Book` somewhere in the process as that is the only place `Page`s and `Word`s come from.

Comment: Wow that is great!